# $x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n+3f(x_n)}{5}$ showing $f$ has a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a differentiable function , and suppose that there is a constant $A<1$ such that $|f'(t)|\le A$ for all real $t$. Define a sequence $\{x_n\}$ by $
   $$$x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n+3f(x_n)}{5}$$

Prove that the sequence  $\{x_n\}$ is convergent and that its limit is the unique fixed point of $f$

I tried using the Banach fixed point theorem but it doesn't seem to apply here

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267648/prove-that-a-function-having-a-derivative-bounded-by-0-49-has-a-unique-solution/267677#267677).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, for any $u, v \in \Bbb R$, we can find $t \in (u, v)$ so that:
$$
\frac{f(u) - f(v)}{u - v} = f'(t)
$$

Given that $\left|f'(t)\right| \le A < 1$, it follows that:
$$
\left|f(u) - f(v)\right| \le A |u - v|
$$

Hence, $f$ is a contraction.

Now define $g(t) = \dfrac{2t + 3f(t)}{5}$. By a simple calculation we find that:
$$
\left|g(u) - g(v)\right| = \left|\dfrac{2(u-v) + 3\left(f(u) - f(v)\right)}{5}\right| \le \dfrac{2 + 3A}{5} |u - v|
$$

Since $A < 1$, $\dfrac{2 + 3A}{5} < 1$ and $g$ is also a contraction.

Now apply the Banach fixed point theorem to $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ to arrive at the desired result.