# Using the Banach Fixed Point Theorem to prove convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

> Use the Banach fixed point theorem to show that
>     the following sequence converges.  What is the limit of this
>     sequence?
>   $$\left(\frac{1}{3},
>        \frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}},
>        \frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}}},
>        \dots\right)$$

I inferred the closed form of the sequence
$$\begin{align}
      x_0 &= \frac{1}{3} \\
      x_n &= \frac{1}{3 + x_{n-1}}
    \end{align}$$

and then the function that would, I assume, be that which would be applied repeatedly to converge the sequence (per the Banach fixed point theorem)
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3+x}$$

---

That's about as far as I know to go *for sure*, but I assumed then that I needed to prove $f(x)$ was a contraction mapping (as the hypothesis of the Banach fixed point theorem dictates), that is

$$d(f(x),f(y)) \leq r d(x,y)$$
where $r \in [0, 1)$, and so

$$    \begin{align}
      \frac{1}{3+x} - \frac{1}{3+y} &\leq r(x - y) \\
      \frac{1}{(x - y)(3 + x)} - \frac{1}{(x - y)(3 + y)} &\leq r \\
      \frac{-1}{(x + 3)(y + 3)} &\leq r
    \end{align}$$

Although I don't think the above proves anything useful at all.  (Unless $(x+3)(y+3) < -1$, where it is shown that $\exists r \in [0,1) : \dots$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track (though you forgot the rather crucial absolute value signs in your inequality). Try showing that $f$ is a contraction map on some *subinterval* of $\Bbb R$. (It isn't even defined at $-3$, so we have to consider a proper subinterval, anyway.) Since we're taking our initial point to be $\frac13$, we might as well consider $[0,\infty)$. We could instead use $[\alpha,\infty)$ for some $-3<\alpha<0$, if we liked, but $0$ works just fine.

Show that if $x\in[0,\infty)$ then $f(x)\in[0,\infty).$ Then for all $x,y\in[0,\infty)$, you can see that $$\left|\frac1{3+x}-\frac1{3+y}\right|=\left|\frac{y-x}{(3+x)(3+y)}\right|=\frac1{(3+x)(3+y)}|x-y|\le r|x-y|,$$ where $r=???$

Comment: Thanks for noticing the absolute value stuff - I define a new command `\abs#1` for that, and MathJax doesn't know how to define new commands ;)  *But* since we know that $|x-y|\geq0$, we can safely simplify out the absolute value (except in the trivial case where $x=y$, where the inequality holds from the get-go).  Then, since $x,y\geq0$, the fraction is strictly positive, satisfying $r\in [0,1)$.  But what about actually finding its limit?

Comment: But wait a minute ... there's no upper bound on $r$ here...

Comment: Since $x,y\ge 0$, then $3+x,3+y\ge 3,$ so $(3+x)(3+y)\ge9$, and so $$\frac1{(3+x)(3+y)}\le\frac19.$$ That's how we get our $r$. As for finding the limit, remember that it will be the fixed point of $f$ in $[0,\infty).$ In particular, it will be the positive solution to $$\frac1{3+x}=x.$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - it seems I was thinking about it all wrong. :)

Comment: Glad to help out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the mean value theorem to prove your map $f(x)=\frac{1}{3+x}$ is contraction on the interval $[0,\infty)$. See here for [detailed techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267648/prove-that-a-function-having-a-derivative-bounded-by-0-49-has-a-unique-solution/267677#267677).