# When does Newton-Raphson Converge/Diverge?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

Is there an analytical way to know an interval where all points when used in Newton-Raphson will converge/diverge?

I am aware that Newton-Raphson is a special case of fixed point iteration, where:

$$ g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} $$

Also I've read that if $|f(x)\cdot f''(x)|/|f'(x)^2| \lt 1$, then convergence is assured. I am just not sure on how to use this fact? Could anyone give me some examples? Thanks.

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: The "fact" can be used to show that the underlying fixed point iteration is a contraction mapping.  Have you looked at it in this perspective?  Is this of interest?

Comment: Explain Newton’s method for f(x) = x
3+x−2 = 0. Show that
Newton’s method converges if x0 ∈ [1−
1/30 , 1+1/30 ] to a limit L. Find an error
estimate for the error en = |xn−L|. (Hint. x
3 −3x
2 +2 = (x−1)(x
2 −2x−2)
and |x
2 − 2x − 2| ≤ 10 if 0 ≤ x ≤ 2.)

Comment: What do you mean? I really didn't understand what the book said about that part it just said that an interval exist such that which ever x i get from [r-e,r+e] will give me convergence...but what the hell is e???

Comment: from the above question. e=1/30. how was that obtained?

Comment: See [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267648/prove-that-a-function-having-a-derivative-bounded-by-0-49-has-a-unique-solution/267677#267677).

Comment: I just got more messed up.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1664117/115115 for the answer to the interval question.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the solution of 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 0,
\end{equation}
where $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is at least two times differentiable with continuous derivatives and has a single root $x=r$ of multiplicity $1$. This last assumption ensures 
\begin{equation}
f'(r) \not = 0
\end{equation}
which will be needed later. Let $x_n$ denote an approximation of $r$ obtained by any means necessary. Then by doing a Taylor expansion at $x=x_n$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
0 = f(r) = f(x_n) + f'(x_n)(r-x_n) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(r-x_n)^2
\end{equation}
or equivalently
\begin{equation}
- f(x_n) = f'(x_n)(r-x_n) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(r-x_n)^2
\end{equation}
for at least one $\xi_n$ between $r$ and $x_n$. This allows us to express Newton's iteration as
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n + \frac{f'(x_n)(r-x_n) + \frac{f''(\xi_n)}{2}(r-x_n)^2}{f'(x_n)}
\end{equation}
While obscure, this representation allows us to immediately conclude that
\begin{equation}
r- x_{n+1} = -\frac{f''(\xi_n)}{2 f'(x_n)}{(r-x_n)^2}
\end{equation}
This is the equation which you can use to show convergence of Newton's method. Let us define the error at the $n$th step as
\begin{equation}
e_n = r - x_n
\end{equation}
then we can write
\begin{equation}
e_{n+1}  = - \frac{f''(\xi_n)}{2 f'(x_n)} e_n^2
\end{equation}
Now since $f'(r) \not = 0$ we can find an interval $I = [r-\delta,r+\delta]$ surrounding the root and determine a constant $M > 0$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\forall : x, y \in I \: : \: \left| \frac{f''(x)}{2 f'(y)} \right| \leq M.
\end{equation}
Here the continuity of $f'$ and $f''$ is critical. Then we can write
\begin{equation}
|e_{n+1}| \leq M |e_n|^2 = (M|e_n|) |e_n|.
\end{equation}
It follows that if $x_0 \in I$ is picked such that 
\begin{equation}
M|e_n| \leq \rho < 1
\end{equation}
then not only will the error decrease, but (and this is critical) $x_1$ will belong to $I$, allowing the argument to be repeated, leading to the (pessimistic) estimate
\begin{equation}
e_n \leq \rho^n |e_0|
\end{equation}
which nevertheless establishes (local) convergence of Newton's method.

As the iteration converges, it will sooner rather than later do so quadratically, as
\begin{equation}
\frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n^2} = - \frac{f''(\xi_n)}{2 f'(x_n)} \rightarrow -\frac{f''(r)}{2 f'(r)}, \quad n\rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}
Here it is critical that Taylor's theorem ensure that $\xi_n$ is betweeen $x_n$ and $r$. Since $x_n \rightarrow r$ the squeeze lemma will ensure that $\xi_n \rightarrow r$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: so how do I find the interval? In the example above how was I=[1-1/30,1+1/30] 1 is the root but how was 1/30 obtained?

Answer (score 3):

A theoretically nice but practically nearly useless answer is provided by the Newton-Kantorovich theorem: If $L=M_2$ is an upper bound for the magnitude of the second derivative over some interval $I$, and with $x_0\in I$ and the first step $s_0=-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$ the "ball" $B(x_0+s_0,|s_0|)=(x_0+s_0-|s_0|,x_0+s_0+|s_0|)$ is contained in $I$ and
$$
L·|f'(x_0)^{-1}|^2·|f(x_0)|\le\frac12
$$
then there is a unique root inside that ball and Newton's method converges towards it.